# How far was Peter from Jesus when he denied him?

Tags: exegesis, gospel-of-luke, peter

In The Gospel of Luke it says:

> Luke 22: 61- and the Lord turned and looked upon Peter. And Peter remembered the word of the Lord, how he had said to him, Before the cock crow, thou shalt deny me thrice

Was Jesus next to him? In films I've seen, it portrayed as such that Jesus walks by arrested or is next to him (or within viewing range) that Peter sees him and breaks down in tears. Or was Peter able to see Jesus wherever he was at this point? Luke is the only gospel to mention he "looked upon" him.
The Bible says "looked upon" not "looked on" . Looked upon however was used in 1 John 1:1 which could mean something more heavenly..but a few other verses don't seem to match this meaning. Such as Mark 16:17. In fact looked upon is not used much at all, even by Jesus.

Answer (score 5):

### Proximity

> (Luk 22:54) Then took they him, and led him, and brought him into the high priest's house. And Peter followed afar off.

This is the question. He followed, from some distance.

> (Luk 22:55) And when they had kindled a fire in the midst of the hall, and were set down together, Peter sat down among them.

The gap is narrowed here. What was the occasion of the fire, the crowd, the spectacle, and Peter with them? Here we are, with Peter, and they, in the midst of the hall. This passage is dedicated to Peter's denial, and his second, and his third; the crow of the cock, which had to come.

> **The Lord turned** (strapheis ho kurios). Second aorist passive participle of strephō, coming verb. Graphic picture drawn by Luke alone (**Robertson**).
>
> G4762
>   στρέφω
>   strephō
>   stref'-o
>   Strengthened from the base of G5157; **to twist, that is, turn quite around or reverse** (literally or figuratively): - convert, turn ((again, back again, self, self about), **Strong**).
>
> **Looked upon Peter** (eneblepsen tōi Petrōi). Ingressive aorist active indicative of enblepō, an old and vivid verb, to glance at (**Robertson**).
>
> ἐμβλέπω
>   emblepō
>   em-blep'-o
>   From G1722 and G991; to look on, that is, (relatively) to observe fixedly, or (absolutely) to discern clearly: - **behold, gaze up, look upon, (could) see** (**Strong**).

Luke is the only one who gives this account, and in such a way, as it is meant, to convey personal affectation; real in this case. The wording is deliberate, in other words. It would be unnatural, and strenuous, to attempt to interpret this, in any way, other than cause and effect.

I agree, as the comment, I see above, that Jesus knew all things. However, Peter did not. Though Jesus told him beforehand, he would learn his heart like we all do; in the trial of our determination.

He "looked back" on Peter; also how Tertullian reads it, making allusion to this, in terms of a sudden awakening, of that knowledge of sin to be repented of.

> "...the occasion indeed demands that I should note down; but (to do so) may seem to be unnecessary. For when the Lord is known, our spirit, having been” looked back upon” by its own Author, emerges unbidden into the knowledge of the truth (**Tertullian** *On Repentance*: Ante-Nicene Fathers Vol 3."

How close? Close enough to meet each others eyes. Close enough that Jesus was able to hear the denial? We know that Peter was in the court. Verse sixty-two says that he went (escaped), out (outside, of doors), and wept bitterly. (The morpho. analys. are taking up more room than I would like. I will supply them @ req.).

Mark 11:11? Because, I see no relation in this to Mark 16:17, but 11:11 he looked round upon, different; and 1 John 1:1

> θεάομαι
>   theaomai
>   theh-ah'-om-ahee
>   A prolonged form of a primary verb; to look closely at, that is, (by implication) to perceive (literally or figuratively); by extension to visit: - behold, look (upon), see. Compare G3700 (**Strong**).

Also different. I feel like Tertullian captured it, in a separate, though not unrelated, context. In an almost mystical, naked, and revealing sense.

### Conclusion

It may be conjecture, but, Peter was close enough to hear, to be heard, and to be seen.

> 1. Robertson, Archibald T. *Word Pictures in the New Testament* Published in 1930-1933; public domain. See Luke 22:61 this commentary.
> 2. Strong, James. S.T.D., LL.D., 1890. W/TVM

Answer (score 0):

Peter was close to Jesus that night in the courtyard of the home of Caiaphas the High Priests home where Jesus was being tried and accused. In [chapter 23](https://www.jw.org/en/publications/books/true-faith/peter-learned-forgiveness-from-jesus/) of the book Imitate their Faith published by Jehovah's  Witnesses  the evening of this occurrence is discussed in some detail and below I have inserted what it says as it picks up in the garden when the mob was leading Jesus away:

> Jesus reasoned with the mob that if they were looking for him, they should let his apostles go. Peter watched helplessly as the mob bound Jesus. Then Peter fled, as did his fellow apostles.
>
> Peter and John stopped in their flight, perhaps near the house of the former High Priest Annas, where Jesus was first taken for questioning. As Jesus was led from there, Peter and John followed but “at a good distance.” (Matt. 26:58; John 18:12, 13) Peter was no coward. It surely took a measure of courage to follow at all. The mob was armed, and Peter had already wounded one of them. Still, we do not here see in Peter’s example the kind of loyal love that he himself had professed—a willingness to die by his Master’s side if need be.—Mark 14:31
>
> Like Peter, many today seek to follow Christ “at a good distance”—in such a way that no one else will notice. But as Peter himself later wrote, the only way to follow Christ properly is to stick as close to Him as we can, imitating His example in all things, regardless of the consequences.—Read 1 Peter 2:21.
>
> Peter’s cautious steps finally brought him up to the gate of one of Jerusalem’s most imposing mansions. It was the home of Caiaphas, the wealthy and powerful high priest. Such homes were usually built around a courtyard, with a gate in the front. Peter reached the gate and was refused entrance. John, who knew the high priest and was already inside, came and got the doorkeeper to admit Peter. It seems that Peter did not stick close to John; nor did he try to get inside the house to stand at his Master’s side. He stayed in the courtyard, where some slaves and servants were passing the chilly night hours in front of a bright fire, watching as the false witnesses against Jesus paraded in and out of the trial going on inside.—Mark 14:54-57; John 18:15, 16, 18.
>
> In the firelight, the girl who had admitted Peter at the gate was able to see him better. She recognized him. She said accusingly: “You, too, were with Jesus the Galilean!” Caught off guard, Peter denied knowing Jesus—or even understanding what the girl was talking about. He went to stand near the gatehouse, trying to be inconspicuous, but another girl noticed him and pointed out the same fact: “This man was with Jesus the Nazarene.” Peter swore: “I do not know the man!” (Matt. 26:69-72; Mark 14:66-68) Perhaps it was after this second denial that Peter heard a cock crowing, but he was too distracted to be reminded of the prophecy Jesus had uttered just hours earlier.
>
> A little while later, Peter was still trying desperately to escape notice. But a group of people standing around in the courtyard approached. One of them was related to Malchus, the slave whom Peter had wounded. He said to Peter: “I saw you in the garden with him, did I not?” Peter felt driven to convince them that they were wrong. So he swore to the matter, evidently saying that a curse should come upon him if he was lying. That was Peter’s third denial. No sooner were the words out of his mouth than a cock crowed—the second one Peter heard that night.—John 18:26, 27; Mark 14:71, 72.
>
> Jesus had just come out onto a balcony overlooking the courtyard. In that moment, described at the outset of this chapter, his eyes met Peter’s. It dawned on Peter just how terribly he had failed his Master. Peter left the courtyard, crushed by the weight of his own guilt. He headed into the streets of the city, his way lit by the sinking full moon. The tears welled up. The sights swam before his eyes. He broke down and wept bitterly.—Mark 14:72; Luke 22:61, 62.

So from the scriptures we can say that Peter was on the grounds of the home of Caiaphas, while Jesus was inside, when the denial took place.